# no jogl in java.library.path in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jogl

simple example code in `CGUsingJava2d3d`, I have problem with

```
GLCanvas canvas = GLDrawableFactory.getFactory().createGLCanvas(cap);
```

I added jar files `jogl-all`, `jogl_old` and argument `-Djava.library.path=----` to link with jogl's dll files.

And, those files come from

http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL

(dll files from \jogamp-all-platforms\lib\windows-amd64)

This is source code....just in case.

```
package chapter1;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.java.games.jogl.*;

public class JOGLDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame("JOGL Demo");
    GLCapabilities cap = new GLCapabilities();
    GLCanvas canvas = GLDrawableFactory.getFactory().createGLCanvas(cap);
    canvas.setSize(300, 300);
    canvas.addGLEventListener(new Renderer());
    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.pack();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    frame.show();
  }

  static class Renderer implements GLEventListener {
    private GL gl;
    private GLU glu;
    private GLDrawable gldrawable;

    public void init(GLDrawable drawable) {
      gl = drawable.getGL();
      glu = drawable.getGLU();
      this.gldrawable = drawable;
      gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
      gl.glLoadIdentity();
      glu.gluOrtho2D(-1.2, 1.2, -1.2, 1.2);
      gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }    

    public void display(GLDrawable drawable) {
      int i;
      int n = 80;
      float a = (float)(2*3.1415926535/n);
      float x;
      float y;

      gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      gl.glColor3f(1.0f,0,0);
      gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP);
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x = (float)Math.cos(i*a);
        y = (float)Math.sin(i*a);
        gl.glVertex2f(x, y);
      }
      gl.glEnd();
      gl.glFlush();
    }

    public void reshape(GLDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width,
      int height) {}
    public void displayChanged(GLDrawable drawable, boolean modeChanged,
      boolean deviceChanged) {}
  }
}
```

Please, tell me what I have to do more or check somthing..

Have a good day. Thanks.

Comment: You have to add `jogl-all.jar` and `gluegen-rt.jar` and their corresponding natives, that is for windows x64 `jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar` and `gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar`, it works also if you don't add the natives explicitely but you just leave them there together with the first two listed jar. Ps: you shouldn't use deprecated OpenGL, here a simple modern [Hello Triangle](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no chance to work, it uses an old pre-version of JOGL 1. Use com.jogamp.opengl instead and look at our documentation.

I agree with elect's comment.